# PHPで保存したファイルの所有者について

Tags: php, macos, apache

Mac Yosemite 上の Apache でローカルで動かしてます。
PHPで以下のように実行ユーザーを表示してみると、

```
echo get_current_user();
```

すると"_www"になるんですが、テキストファイルを保存してみるとその所有者は"自分の名前"になっています。
実行ユーザーと所有者が別々(グループも別々です)になるわけですが、これはどういう設定からなっていることなんでしょうか？
ちなみに、対象フォルダのパーミッションは0755で、suEXECは有効になっていません。それと、PHP はモジュール版です。

---

追記
実行したコードです。

```
echo 'user:' . get_current_user() . '<br>';

$file_handle = fopen("test.txt", "w");

if($file_handle){
    $wr = fwrite($file_handle , "あいうえお\nかきくけこ");

    if($wr == FALSE){
        echo "fwrite 失敗<br>";
    }else{
        echo "fwrite 成功<br>";
    }

    fclose($file_handle);
}else{
    echo "fopen 失敗<br>";
}
```

所有者、グループの確認は Finder の「右クリック - 情報を見る」からしました。
その後、httpd.conf も見てグループも違っていると思ったということです。

Comment: ちょっと気になったので調べてみたのですが、PHPの`get_current_user()`は実行ユーザー名ではなく、スクリプトの所有者名を返すとのことです。 [PHP: get_current_user - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.get-current-user.php)

Comment: テキストファイルを保存して、というのは、PHPのプログラムでそういう処理をした、ということですか？たとえば`file_put_contents("/tmp/test.txt", "hoge")`をやったら/tmp/test.txtの所有者が自分になっている、ということでしょうか。

Comment: すみません、「テキストファイルを保存」ではなく「テキストファイルを作成」の間違いでした。

Comment: get_current_user の理解不足でした。しかし、httpd.conf で `User _www` になってる場合は "_www" の所有者でファイルが作成される、ということではないんでしょうか？

Comment: 「保存」と「作成」に重大な違いがあるとはおもえないのですが、具体的に何をやったのか、その結果をどう確認したのかを書いてもらえませんか。(コメントではなく質問に追記してください)

Comment: 質問の本筋とは違いますが。今、test.php を実行してます。test.php の所有者は"自分"です。しかし、get_current_user() は "_www" を返します。「スクリプトの所有者」とは「test.php の所有者」の事でないんなら何なんでしょうか？

Comment: posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())で実行ユーザーの情報をarrayで取得できるかと思いますが`echo posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];`はどうなってますか？

Comment: `echo posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];`は"_www"になってます。

Comment: Finder からじゃなくて、ターミナル上から該当ファイルの所有者を見たらどう見えるんでしょうか？

Comment: `ls -l`で見ると"自分"になってます。

Comment: test.txtは元々あったファイルとかではないですよね？(上書きではないですよね？)

Comment: 無かったファイルを PHP で作っています。上書きではないです。

Answer (score 2):

OS X標準のapacheでmod_phpを有効にして、DocumentRootになっている/Library/WebServer/Documentsに上記スクリプトをおいて実行しましたが書き込みができませんでした。ディレクトリをchmod 777したところ実行できました。ファイルの所有者は_wwwでした。

ということで、少なくとも標準状態+最低限の変更では質問のような動作にはなりません。

一般論としてもapache+mod_php環境ではapacheの実行ユーザーでPHPスクリプトも実行されますので、上記動作に矛盾はありません。

ということで、その通りの動作になっていないと言うことはここに書いた以上の作業をされていると思いますがその詳細がわからないとこの回答が限界です。

また、「既存のファイルに書き込みを繰り返しているだけ」とか、「スクリプトが作成してるファイルと確認しているファイルが違う」とか、そういうところも疑ったほうがいいかとおもいます。

Comment: こちらではサイト(Sites)フォルダの配下のフォルダにバーチャルホストを設定して各サイトを表示しています。中には「直接のフォルダ」の物と「外部HDD内フォルダのシンボリックリンク」の物とがあります。それでその両方でテストしてみると、「直接のフォルダ」の方はsuzukisさんの書かれている通りの動きでした。「外部HDD内フォルダのシンボリックリンク」の方で質問のような状態になりました。このようなことは関係あるんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

ターミナルから設定ファイルを見るとこのようにでました

```
$ cat /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf | grep  -n "_www"
181:User _www
182:Group _www
```

Comment: こちらの環境でも httpd.conf 内で、  <br />
    User _www  
    Group _www  
となっています。

Comment: コメントの書き方を分かってなくて変になってて、すみません。